# Replace a part of a string using a math factor

Tags: sql, regex, powershell, replace

I am using PowerShell and MS Access.

I would like to apply a math factor to what is inside the pipes in this column value.

Ex. -100.0 must become -400.0 and 100.0 must become 400.0, given the factor is 4.

I only need to modify "Min_Value" and "Max_Value" tokens (hard coded).

FiledValue comes from the database (there are multiple rows).

FieldValue isn't always exactly the same as this example, BUT the token pattern is always the same Ex. Min_Value=|.....|

```
function Test
{
$Factor = 4

# Hard-coded SQL query result
$FieldValue = "Min_Value=|-100.0|;Max_Value=|100.0|;COMM_ID1=|1|;"

# Compare this value with a regular expression (Issue A: This doesn't work because of the minus sign and decimal)
if ($FieldValue -match "Min_Value=\|([0-9]+)\|;Max_Value=\|([0-9]+)\|;")
{   
    # Trying to retreive -100.0 here...(Issue B: this doesn't work). I beleive I can only specify ||, not Min_Value=||
    $TokenMinValue = $FieldValue.Split('Min_Value=||')[1]
    $TokenMaxValue = $FieldValue.Split('Max_Value=||')[1]

    # Trying to take the token (-100.0), multiply it by 4 and write it back where I found it (Issue C: this obvioulsy doesn't work)
    $Result = $FieldValue -replace "$regex",($TokenMinValue * $Factor)
    $Result = $FieldValue -replace "$regex",($TokenMaxValue * $Factor)

    #The goal is for $Result to equal "Min_Value=|-400.0|;Max_Value=|400.0|;COMM_ID1=|1|;"
}
}
```

Comment: Is 2 & 3 even possible in SQL ?

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is how I solved it:

$factor = 25.4
$minRegex = "Min_Value=\|([-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)\|;" 
$maxRegex = "Max_Value=\|([-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)\|;"
$modif = 0

if ($FieldValue -match $minRegex)
{     
  $token = $matches[1]
  $replacement = "Min_Value=|" + ([convert]::ToDouble($token) * $factor) + "|;"
  $FieldValue = $FieldValue -replace $minRegex, $replacement 
  $modif = 1     
}

// Idem for max                

if ($modif) // do UPDATE query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS so here's a solution using `Postgres`. At least you can follow the logic behind it:

```
select 
  concat(
    replace(
      concat('Min_Value=|', string_agg(intval,';')), ';', '|;Max_Value=|'),
    '|;') 
from (
  select (unnest(regexp_matches('Min_Value=|10|;Max_Value=|100|;', 'Min_Value=\|([0-9]+)\|;Max_Value=\|([0-9]+)\|;'))::int*4)::TEXT as intval  
  ) foo;
```

The magic happens like that:

1. with `regexp_matches` extract two integers from input string
2. use `unnest` to unpack the array into two separate rows
3. cast those integer values (which are text at the moment) to `Integer` and multiply by factor `4`
4. use `string_agg` with `;` as delimiter to make one string row containing both integers delimited with `;`
5. use `concat` to append `Min_Value=|` at the beginning, so the string is now `Min_Value=|40;400`
6. use `replace` and replace `;` with next part - `|;Max_Value=|` so the string is now `Min_Value=|40|;Max_Value=|400`
7. use `concat` again to append `|;` to the end of the string

**Input:**

```
Min_Value=|10|;Max_Value=|100|;
```

**Result:**

```
Min_Value=|40|;Max_Value=|400|;
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I modified my question to be more on target.

Comment: Basically nothing works from what you've posted. Try something yourself please. Basic regex knowledge would solve issue A. Then basic Powershell knowledge would solve issue B...